# non-customized devise reset password button is doing absolutely nothing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise login and logout working, been using it for a while now.

I have not copied devise's password controller or password views to my application, just using the out of the box form for password/new. After entering the email of a valid user, when I click the "send me password reset instructions" button, nothing happens. I checked my logs and there is no activity post-click. I've read through devise documentation but it doesn't seem like there is any special setup steps to get the reset password functionality working. What could be wrong?

For more context, I have followed [devise's instructions](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in) for requiring admin to activate account before sign in. I have pulled the registrations and sessions controllers into my app for minimal customization, though that doesn't seem like it should matter. I'm using rails 4.2.0.rc2 and devise 3.4.1

Here's the rendered html for the form:

```html
  <h2>Forgot your password?</h2>

<form class="new_user" id="new_user" action="/users/password" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="AE+YY8afzRavKa1ziDFZ5Z6FqFYQF1vI+zvc701JGqfg5k+ztvMIKHDX4Wdfr+KOp9yEcRBTsk4jfonpzUeP5w==" />
  

  <div class="field">
    <label for="user_email">Email</label><br />
    <input autofocus="autofocus" type="email" value="" name="user[email]" id="user_email" />
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <input type="submit" name="commit" value="Send me reset password instructions" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you see any email activity in the dev console? Are you using "Ajax"?

Comment: Can you show us some of your rendered HTML?

Comment: I'm looking at the rails server logs (debug level) and there's nothing, meaning when I click the button there is no log of any activity. (Btw I do have emails working in other places, through ActionMailer.) I will paste in the rendered HTML in a minute.

Comment: @errata's question about using ajax helped. I didn't build the front end, and am not familiar with ajax. Just to see, I commented the header and footer and now the form is working. So I guess there is some ajax type conflict, looking into it now.

Comment: I guess the rails server logs are not enough, in terms of monitoring. is there a better way to monitor everything that's happening in the app in real time?

Comment: Its called the browser console: [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Tools/Web_Console), [The Browser That Should Not Be Named](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589530%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your javascript is preventing the form from being submitted unless a terms-of-service field is checked.

from your application.js file:

```
if $('#user_terms').is(':checked')
else
  e.preventDefault()
  $('#terms-of-service-error').modal()
return
```